# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, How do i rectify this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React and Redux to fetch data from my parse server. The dispatch is being dispatched fine but im not able to display the data from mapstatetoprops in the function. Is there something im missing out ?
Please help me out from this

This is my Component Profileheader.js

```js
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import Cover_Image from './Cover_Image.jpg';
import Profile_Pic from './Profile_Pic.svg';
import './ProfileHeader.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchUserProfile} from '../../Redux/UserProfile-Redux/UserProfileActionMethods';



function ProfileHeader({Data,fetchUserProfile}){
    useEffect(()=>{fetchUserProfile();},[]);
    return Data.isLoading ? (<h2>Loading...</h2>) :
            Data.error ? (<h2>{Data.error}</h2>) :
            (
                <div>
                    {
                        Data.userprofiles.map((user)=>{
                            return(
                                <div> 
                                    <p>{user.attributes.handle}</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            )
}   
   
 const mapStatetoProps = (state) =>{
     return{
        //from the rootreducer
        Data:state.UserProfile
     }
 }

 const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
       fetchUserProfile:()=>{dispatch(fetchUserProfile())},dispatch,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps,mapDispatchtoProps)(ProfileHeader)
```

It's Action Methods,

```js
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';
import { FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE, FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST, FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS } from './UserProfileActions';

const params = {username:"prvnngrj"}

export const fetchUserProfileRequest = () => {
    return{
        type:FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST
    }
}

export const fetchUserProfileSuccess = (userprofiles) =>{
    return{
        type:FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS,
        payload:userprofiles
    }
}

export const fetchUserProfileFailure = (error) =>{
    return{
        type:FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE,
        payload:error
    }
}

export const fetchUserProfile = () => {
    return async dispatch =>{
        dispatch(fetchUserProfileRequest())
        try{
            const responsedata = await Parse.Cloud.run("GetUserProfileForUsername", params);
            const userprofiles = responsedata;
            dispatch(fetchUserProfileSuccess(userprofiles))
        
        }
        catch(error){
            const errorMessage = error.message
            dispatch(fetchUserProfileFailure(errorMessage))
        }
    }

}
```

This is the reducer.

```js
import { FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE, FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST, FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS } from "./UserProfileActions"

const initialState = {
    isLoading:false,
    userprofiles:[],
    error:''
}

export const UserProfileReducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST :
            return{...state,
                isLoading:true
            }
        case FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS :
            return{
                isLoading:false,
                usersprofiles:action.payload,
                error:''
            }    
        case FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE :
            return{
                isLoading:false,
                usersprofiles:[],
                error:action.payload
            }    
        default:
            return state    
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry for the error, I had mispelt userProfiles in userReducer so it couldn't accept the data. The solution is figured !! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The `Data.userProfiles` is either not an array or null. Check the type or ensure that it is initialized to an empty array.

Comment: But when i am logging the data in the console, im able to view the result, but im not able to perform the map.I'm new to all this.How do I initialize the Data as an array and use it in mapStatetoProps?

Comment: What do you see when you log Data.userprofiles?

Comment: You're right. As it enters the function it's nullified. Is their any solution ?

Comment: What are you getting in the `action.payload`

Comment: The problem was a misspelled reducer. Thank you for your time btw

Answer (score 0):

I would add another check for null|undefined and array has items for `userprofiles`

```
return Data.isLoading ? (<h2>Loading...</h2>) :
            Data.error ? (<h2>{Data.error}</h2>) :
            Data.userprofiles && Data.userprofiles.length > 0 ? 
            (
                 <div>.....</div>
            ) : null
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are mapping the content of `Data.userprofiles` is undefined. Try optional chaining like so:

```
Data?.userprofiles?.map((user) => {
...
```